# not able to install anything because of brew no such file or directory error

Tags: permissions, directory, homebrew, mkdir

I am trying to install do `brew install python3` on my mac but i keep getting the following errors:

this is the first error:

> No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /usr/local/Cellar

then a bit later i get this error:

> An exception occurred within a child process:
>     Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Cellar

I have ran `brew update` then `brew doctor` the `brew cleanup` but keep getting the error.
I have also checked to see if xcode is up-to-date but according to the appstore all my apps are up-to-date.

How do i fix this problem?

**PS** i also get these errors when trying to install other packages from brew.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try uninstalling Homebrew and then re-installing solved issue for me.

Uninstall Homebrew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

Re-install Homebrew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Performed in MacOS Mojave (10.14.4)

Comment: This make me resintall tmux

Comment: Dont do this, it will make you reinstall a lot of stuff

Comment: **Uninstalling Homebrew will also uninstall a lot of your installed packages.**

Comment: that means uninstalling all formaulae with it..!

Comment: Worked for me on linux. After uninstalling and before reinstalling, I threw in a `rm -rf /home/linuxbrew` for good measure.

Comment: When doing this, and not removing all applications, brew returns after the reinstall a empty list. Even when applications are installed which where installed by brew.
Not a good solution.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS. THIS WILL UNINSTALL A LOT OF THINGS

Comment: DO NOT DO this - makes things worse

Answer (score 51):

Happened to me when uninstalling Laravel Valet.

Fixed by running: `brew doctor`, then `brew cleanup` after.
After that - `brew install php` worked just fine.

Comment: This is it, Try it out and it'll work.

Comment: Yep this worked perfectly... should be best answer

Comment: It works for me, but it's not the answer to this question because OP has done these already.

Comment: The best answer!

Answer (score 10):

I experienced a similar error with a different package - `brew install llvm`.

Uninstalling homebrew and reinstalling led to more catastrophic issues that lasted for hours before I had to reach for my backup drive and restore everything. 
What eventually worked was just creating the missing directory and everything worked.
So in this case:

`sudo mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/dir_chdir`

should solve the issue without too much hustle.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me after running below commands

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/dir_chdir
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar
chmod u+w /usr/local/Cellar
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well - it was partly coming from brew being installed under a different user on my mac I had set up for a past project. I had to follow the uninstall instructions (found in the [homebrew github](https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew)) with a little bit of sudo help and it cleared up the issue. Was able to install and properly run packages after.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For ubuntu just go to the location which u are getting error. Then open the contained file using a suitable application. In my case, it is getting as follows in the image view.

[image]

In this case, the error is showing in 36's lines.

[image]

yes. There is no location such as. I have to find out the location which contains brew. It was in `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew//bin/brew shellenv`

So update your .profile file as in the brew file contains location as follows image shown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

uninstall brew :

```bash
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

and again reinstall brew:

```bash
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

executed this same as it is on your terminal, it will really work.

Answer (score 0):

These commands worked for me!

```bash
brew doctor
brew autoremove
brew cleanup
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing sudo i was getting this error: bash: /bin/brew: No such file or directory.

i fixed it like this. Open your .bashrc file.

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

and close the last line as a comment.

```
#eval "$(/bin/brew shellenv)"
```