# 'Brew install php' leads to error 'Error: No such file or directory'

Tags: php, homebrew

Hi recently I upgraded my mac and this has caused some serious issues with my php installation. I previously installed this using homebrew so I tried reinstalling php by uninstalling it and then running `brew install php`. However now I'm getting this error: `Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/php`. I've tried searching for this error everywhere but couldn't find a similar case. Can anybody explain this error and maybe point in a direction on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [not able to install anything because of brew no such file or directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54543697/not-able-to-install-anything-because-of-brew-no-such-file-or-directory-error)

Comment: Thanks but no, because it did let me install other packages it was just PHP and I didn't want to reinstall homebrew because as mentioned in that answer it also uninstalls all other installed packages. In the end I 'solved' it by installing composer with brew, which required the latest version of PHP and it automatically installed that without the error. Still a bit weird how this happened.

Answer (score 5):

Try to remove `php` symlink from the `/usr/local/var/homebrew/linked`

```
rm /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/php
```

Answer (score 0):

try this algorithm:

1. `brew update`
2. `brew cleanup`
3. `brew install php`