# all brew commands are giving error: An exception occurred within a child process

Tags: homebrew

I was facing some issue with valet working, and I tried the solution given on the link [not able to install anything because of brew no such file or directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54543697/not-able-to-install-anything-because-of-brew-no-such-file-or-directory-error) .

Although I stopped the brew uninstallation in the middle on reading the comments below the verified answer, I guess it still caused some issues with brew. I am getting error,

> **"Error: An exception occurred within a child process:"**

with a different child process each time. Even **brew upgrade** is raising same error.

Can anyone guide me about how this issue can be solved?